# Add 2nd Series/Bar in the Charts in WinForms using C# and SQL Server database

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to add another series on the name of "Pending Cases" in the same chart using C# and SQL Server. I want to show bars of "Disposal Cases" and "Pending Cases" on the same chart. I have wrote the query for the Disposal Cases as in the cmd. But i am confused to add the 2nd bar in the chart on the same date. Means on the single i will have Pending Case and Disposed Cases.

Method is below along with SQL query...

```
public void ChartReportAllDaily()
{
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NextDate, COUNT(CaseNo) AS DailyDisposal FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List WHERE (DisposalState = 'Disposed-of') GROUP BY NextDate", conn);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "Main_Cause_List");

            chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Main_Cause_List"];

            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "NextDate";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "DailyDisposal";

            // To show chart value  
            chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
           
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is the ChartType Bar or Column? What does it look like so far and how should it look after? Is `NextDate` a Date or a DateTime? Or a number? Or a string?? Have already added the 2nd Series?

Comment: Yes Sir,, The Type is Bar...and I want to group them on the date.

Comment: If those dates are corresponding (exactly, ie no tme fractions) then a 2nd series will show its bars besides those of the 1st series. Did you try? Do you have the select working?

Comment: i just need date no need if time sir...

Comment: I didn't ask about what you need but what you actually have.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
try
{
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NextDate, COUNT(CaseNo) AS DailyDisposal FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List WHERE (DisposalState = 'Disposed-of') GROUP BY NextDate", conn);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "Main_Cause_List");

            chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Main_Cause_List"];
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "NextDate";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "DailyDisposal";

            // To show chart value  
            chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
           
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;

            //////////////////////////////
            SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NextDate, COUNT(CaseNo) AS DailyPending FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List WHERE (DisposalState = 'Pending')  GROUP BY NextDate", conn);

            SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter();
            daa.SelectCommand = cmdd;
            daa.Fill(ds, "Main_Cause_List");

            chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Main_Cause_List"];
            chart1.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "NextDate";
            chart1.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "DailyDisposal";

            // To show chart value  
            chart1.Series["Series2"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be an answer? If not please edit the question. If so, please explain! Btw: The upper chart shows no bars but columns!

Comment: Sorry I was wrong....Typographical mistake sir,,,thank you for clarification...@TaW